# Unable to locate button via Selenium for Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to find the Login-Button on a website via Selenium WebDriver and click it. 
The HTML-Code is as following:

```
<a class="myLoginButton" href="#" 
onclick="fireLoginOrRegisterModalRequest('sign_in');ga('send', 'event', 
'service_navigation', 'login', '1st_level');">
Login
</a>
```

But no matter which method I use to locate this button I always get the error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

I already tried the following:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('myLoginButton')
login_button.click()

# login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Login"]')
# login_button = 
# driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='myLoginButton'] 
# [.='Login']")
# login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('myLoginButton')
```

The commented lines are the alternative methods I used.

Please be gentle with me. I am an absolute Python and Selenium newbie.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you miss the lines about get the url, try to set a sleep after that, before you try to get the element, or make some function to check if the website is fully loaded. Also this  wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH .....)) is nice to use

Comment: Please check whether a tag element is child element of iframe. If so, you have to switch to frame and then you can click the element

Comment: Check for the presence of any iframes. You will get this error if you dont propertly switch to the frame.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no iFrame present.

Answer (score 0):

In case that there is iFrame (login form contained within an iframe), then you need to switch into.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10
driver.switch_to.frame('Example')
login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('myLoginButton')
login_button.click()
```

Comment: The user should usually locate the iframe element first, before switching to it. The code would be `iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//iframe[@class='someClass']")` then `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`

Comment: The login is not contained in an iFrame.
I can provide more of the HTML Code if that would help.

Comment: Can you please post the full html code  or url here?